# Using AzCopy to copy data from one storage account to another?

Tags: azure, azure-storage, azcopy

I want to write a batch script that copies all the files from one of my storage account to another. I'm using AzCopy and this works but it only copies files from one container. I wanted to know how can I iterate over all the containers in my storage account inside my batch script and then copy the whole container over to the other account.

Getting a list of containers and iterating over them is where I seem to be stuck.

Answer (score 2):

As far as i know, there is no automated way to move all containers at once in existing tools. The closest way to do that without programming i see is to use Powershell:

Execute Get-AzureStorageContainer to get the list of containers
 -> using simple loop, iterate through each container and execute the [copy code (for a reference).](http://windowsitpro.com/azure/copy-content-one-azure-storage-account-another)

Comment: Your link is not active for copy